# ASN.1 UPER decoding in Swift / Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin, asn.1

I need to create native mobile apps (Kotlin / Swift) that are consuming ASN.1 UPER encoded messages. Decoding those is a significant challenge since I am struggling to find any libraries that could help with that. I am starting to think that the task is impossible.

Any help and guideline would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shabby possibility.

Provided you have the ASN1 schema for the data, it's easy to use an asn1 compiler to generate C code to parse received Data into C structs. There is some relatively good open source compilers.

The issue then is how to call that from Swift or Kotlin. The best way might be to have a C++ process for handling the ASN1 data and transcribing the C structs into Google Protocol Buffer objects. Build these using a GPB proto file that is analogous to the asn1 schema. Serialise and send these GPB objects via ZeroMQ to your Kotlin / Swift processes. I'm assuming that there are Kotlin and swift versions of ZeroMQ and GPB.

This is a round about way, but it might be the easiest!

**UPER**.

UPER wire format is non canonical. That is, you cannot interpret the data without knowledge of the original schema. If you don't have the original ASN1 schema for the data, then you will not be able to interpret it.

**Commercial Tools**

There are commercial tools that compile asn1 to Java, which Kotlin can call.

The objective systems tools support python, which may be callable from swift. Python itself has code first approaches to using asn1, which maybe another way.